# Nexus 7 Google Logo Boot-Loop

Tags: nexus-7, boot, boot-loop, fastboot, troubleshooting

My stock Nexus 7 was working fine until I turned it on. The lock screen was frozen. I then hard reset the device and turned it back on. On boot the tablet gets stuck on the Google logo and never continues. Tried recovery mode, but it doesn't start. I also tried re-flashing stock from [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#razor) but it hasn't made a difference. How can I fix this? Can I resolve this with fastboot?

Comment: I would reset the whole thing using Wugfresh's Nexus toolkit. It has saved me from a few panics with my Nexus 7.

Answer (score -1):

Try clearing/formatting Cache partition from recovery and than flash a factory image.

If it doesn't work, flash a custom recovery and than format the Cache partition and try rebooting your Nexus 7.